Use Power Query to consolidate rows (like Pivot Table, but maybe something else)
(Very simplified) I have data like this that I get after a complex series of steps in Power Query.

Previously, I used a Macro to create a Pivot table like so:

But I was hoping to get away from that.  Is there a way to use Power Query to get the same result that the Pivot Table provides me, namely that it consolidates the person into one line so that I don't end up double counting the FTE?
(And you may ask where is the FTE being double counted?  Well, I do actually have a bunch of macros that I subsequently run off the table that are already built and I'm trying to avoid having to modify them by)

I would use index() with match(), so many examples exist on here already so check them out.

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Grouped = Table.Group(Source, {"First", "FTE"}, {{"Sum of Regular", each List.Sum([Regular]), type number}, {"Sum of Extra", each List.Sum([Extra]), type number}})
in
    Grouped


Is there a way to build this using the Power Query buttons?  Like, do I select "First" and "FTE" columns, and then do something via the menus?
Because my real data is much more complicated.  Instead of just First name and FTE, there are like 15 columns of information, and then 4 columns that would be the Values.  How would you modify the above for both the Regular and Extra columns?

@lljc00 - not sure I can answer such a general question but you can start working from the above.  I think it's fairly simple to see how each columns are being groupped.

Here is how you do it via the UI: https://i.sstatic.net/TOPCzcJj.png
